# How to display iPhone/iOS device on Projector?

Tags: iphone, ios, projector

I want to display my iPod screen in my PowerPoint slide show, or on a projector through WiFi.

How can I do that?

I mean something like what TeamViewer can do.

Comment: You need to register your account to gain ownership of this question again.

Comment: This question might be better if it listed which iPod you have. With the iOS iPod Touch and various classic and previous generation iPods you will have differing capabilities and tools to connect to any given projector.

Answer (score 7):

Three possibilities:

- Use AppleTV.
- Use an appropriate adapter, such as an [Apple Digital AV adapater](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC953ZM/A) or [Apple VGA adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/B?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE). (Works only if you have a 4th generation iPod Touch.)
- Use a document camera to record and project your device's screen. For demos where you want to show interaction with the device, this is a common setup.